# Ember #each won't iterate over array

Tags: ember.js

I'm experiencing a really weird behaviour wherein I have an Ember array that has a length, a first object, but I can't iterate over it.

I have a session object which queries the user's team members:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),

  ...

  teamMembers: Ember.computed('token', function() {
    const promise = this.get('store').findAll('teamMember', {include: 'user,organization'});
    return DS.PromiseObject.create({ promise: promise });
  })
});
```

As far as I can see this is working correctly, because when I access it from inside my template, I can access the array length, and the first object:

```
<p>The length of the array is {{session.teamMembers.length}}</p>
<p>The first entry in the array is {{session.teamMembers.firstObject.name}}</p>
```

These work perfectly, returning 2 and my own name, respectively. However, when expressed as an each statement, it returns nothing:

```
<ul>
  {{#each session.teamMembers as |teamMember|}}
    <li>{{teamMember.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The ul element is completely empty. If I have an {{else}} clause, the else clause appears until the promise fulfills, and then I'm left with an empty ul element. The Ember Inspector shows all the values have been loaded correctly.

If I change the method as follows:

```
teamMembers: Ember.computed('token', function() {
  return [{name: 'Paul Doerwald', role: 'lead'}, {name: 'Justin Trudeau', role: 'member'}];
})
```

Then everything works as expected.

I'm clearly doing something wrong in the teamMembers method, presumably returning the wrong array type or something, but I can't figure out what.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For array there is [DS.PromiseArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseArray.html). Wrapping promise into this will make it work with each helper as is. You can use if guard around to display loading state.

```
//service
teamMembers: Ember.computed('token', function() {
  const promise = this.get('store').findAll('teamMember', {include: 'user,organization'});
  return DS.PromiseArray.create({promise});
})

// template
{{#if session.teamMembers.isFulfilled}}
  {{#each session.teamMembers as |teamMember|}}
    <li>{{teamMember.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  loading...
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I also saw addon that provide promisified each helper, but no longer remember where.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't make a difference. :(

Comment: Oh, maybe 'each session.teamMembers.content'

Comment: That worked! But then how do I fix my original query? I have tried changing const promise = this.get('store').findAll('teamMember', {include: 'user,organization'}).then(function(tm) {return tm.get('content');}); and leaving the rest the same, but still doesn't work [the way I'd like].

Comment: Ups,.. I didn't read your question properly. You have bug there that causes all that nuisances. I updated my answer..